# WPF Databinding between two usercontrols

Tags: wpf

I'll try to give a bit more details of this question
In a WPF application, on the left side of 'mainwindow' I have a UserControl containing a listBox, like this

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="viewModel" ObjectType="{x:Type vm:TemplateListViewModel}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>   
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox Height="Auto" Name="TemplateList"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=TemplateNames}"     
</StackPanel>
```

As shown, listbox items are fetched from a xml file via viewModel.
Now I have another usercontrol2 containing a Label to echo the selection from "TemplateList". 
Also under this label I have another usercontrol3 containing a datagrid, which data will be fetched from a xml file based on the label, or the selection from the listbox on the left side of the window through usercontrol3's viewmodel.
So the question is how to pass the "SelectedItem" or "SelectedIndex" to viewModel of the Label and datagrid? 
I know it works when I bind a label to a listbox with 'elementName' and Path to 'SelectedItem'. Now I couldn't figure out how to do with usercontrols and 'ObjectDataProvider'. I tried as suggested below couldn't get it to work out. So far for usercontrol2, if I use the same ObjectDataProvider as the above, I can get this label to work as

```
<Label Name="TemplateNameLabel" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=TemplateNames[0]}" />
```

Where 'TemplateNames' if of type 'XmlNodeList' because it was read from xml file. But I really want is something like

```
<Label Name="TemplateNameLabel" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=TemplateNames[SelectedIndex]}" />
```

Can this be done without any command, just like binding to 'elementname' without usercontrol involved? 
Thanks.

Comment: Put a `SelectedItem` property in the ViewModel, and reference that property from a second ViewModel. Composing different parts of the UI is usally resolved by communication between ViewModels, not Views.

Comment: @user2417994, is your question is still apply?

Answer (score 0):

I've removed not important properties to highlight the main:

```
 <ListBox Name="TemplateList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=TemplateNames}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTemplate, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

Note, that you will need **SelectedTemplate** property with public setter of type **TemplateName** - the same type that is used for single element in the **TemplateNames** collection in the **ViewModel**. In that setter you could pass the value to whatever other view-models you need.